# Having trouble submitting question on Stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I am getting cannot submit a question in less than 25 minutes since I don't have reputation points >= 125.  The strange part is that this is the error message I first got this morning.  I've waited what I thought might have been over 25 minutes and still no luck.

I'll try again much later and see if that solves the problem, but I as I said this happened first thing in the morning, after no activity throughout the night.

Oh yeah -- and I'm using Chrome so maybe it's related to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/anyone-else-having-problems-submitting-questions-through-chrome)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, your IP address appears to be shared by multiple users, which is why you're seeing this error.

We're sorry, but we have to have these kinds of protections in to prevent abuse - hopefully, you'll have enough reputation to bypass this check soon.