# Can't post questions to StackOverflow?

Tags: bug, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having trouble submitting question on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114890/having-trouble-submitting-question-on-stackoverflow)

So I'm trying to post a question to StackOverflow, but I keep getting the error that users with less than 125 reputation can only ask one question every 20 minutes.  However, I haven't posted a question in over a week! Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that deleted questions count towards that limit.  Have you asked and then deleted any questions in the last 20 minutes or so?

Comment: @jad nope, more likely the same case as in the dupe.

Comment: Julian - try posting from home or computer with different IP and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at work so I can't do that, but I'll try logging out and seeing if that works

Comment: Seems likely that someone else has been posting that's on the same IP address.  I guess I'll just be waiting and have to try again later!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd In response to your "nope", I'm pretty sure that deleted questions *do* count towards the limit =)  But I agree, the dupe is the culprit here.  I didn't know about that.

Comment: @jad sure, deleted questions count but I would say it's 50/50 chance generally speaking and he said "I haven't posted a question in over a week" - anyway now you know. :)